# printf %s segfaulting - why?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, format-specifiers

I was hoping this would o/p the last letter of my argv[1]:

```
$ cat input_string_fu.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc !=2){
       printf("Error: Invalid syntax\n");
       return 1;
    };

    int a;
    a = strlen(argv[1]);
    if (a >= 2){
        printf("Last char of %s : %c\n", argv[1], argv[1][a-1] );
        printf("Last char of %s : %s\n", argv[1], argv[1][a-1] );
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

I am confused as to why is printf("%s") on argv[1][a-1] segfaulting.

```
$ ./a.out stackoverflow
Last char of stackoverflow : w
Segmentation fault
$
```

Thank you for your time and expertise!

**EDIT 1:**

Thanks for the guidance. TIL, `printf("%s\n", argv[1][a-1]);` was segfaulting because the %s format specification in printf expects the corresponding argument to be a null terminated char array.

either, **(1)** pass a pointer:

```
printf("%s\n", &argv[1][a-1]);
```

or, as :

```
char *ptr = argv[1];
printf("%s\n", &ptr[a-1]);
```

Or, **(2)** use char:

```
printf("%c\n", argv[1][a-1]);
```

Comment: Using incorrect format specifier (`%s` in this case) is undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you want to print the last letter using `%s`, pass a pointer (which none of the 4 answers I see suggests): ` printf("Last char of %s : %s\n", argv[1], &argv[1][a-1]);`

Comment: What made you think you can print the same type of variable with two different specifiers?

Comment: What else would you expect if you want to read from address `'w'` ?

Comment: You probably haven't enabled all the warnings you should - good compilers will help you spot the mismatch here.  For GCC, try `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for starters (`-Wall -Wextra` turns on `-Wformat`, which is what you need here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `%s` format specifier used for string, but you are trying to print character using `%s`.

According to [printf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> **s**
>
> If no l modifier is present: The const char * argument is **expected
>   to be a pointer to an array of character type (pointer to a string)**.
>   Characters from the array are written up to (but not including) a
>   terminating null byte ('\0'); if a precision is specified, no more
>   than the number specified are written. If a precision is given, no
>   null byte need be present; if the precision is not specified, or is
>   greater than the size of the array, the array must contain a
>   terminating null byte.

Answer (score 3):

Because `argv[1][a-1]` is a `char` value, ok for `%c`, not the address of a `char` array zero terminated usable for `%s`.

Answer (score 2):

Format string for second printf `"Last char of %s : %s\n"` requires a pointer to a null-terminated string as a second parameter while you supply char.

Answer (score 0):

In Second line you have to write `%c` Because `%s` need `const char *` argument
and you are passing `const char`

```
 if (a >= 2){
        printf("Last char of %s : %c\n", argv[1], argv[1][a-1] );
        printf("Last char of %s : %c\n", argv[1], argv[1][a-1] );
    }
```